# Как идентифицировать view cреди других с таким же id и текстом

Tags: java, android, test-automation, espresso

Тестирую приложение на андроид. У меня `FrameLayout` в котором меняются фрагменты. 3 из этих фрагментов имеют одинаковую кнопку (с одинаковым текстом и одинаковым идентификатором). И когда я пытаюсь выполнить клик в одном из этих фрагментов, то получаю ошибку:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   com.btandroid:id/saveButton' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
>   Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

И внизу показывается иерархия, куда входят 2 фрагмента с такой кнопкой. 
Можно ли задать как-то, что надо жать только на видимую кнопку или еще как-то унифицировать?

Answer (score 3):

Уже нашла. Там есть ViewMatchers.isCompletelyDisplayed(), который видимо выбирает только то, что на экране. Во всяком случае у меня сработало.

Comment: ViewMatchers.isCompletelyDisplayed() по сути так и работает, он вроде перебирает список View.getVisibility. Поэтому вы не обращаетесь к кнопкам с этим же id др. фрагментов.  Только вам надо будет учитывать обстоятельства, когда вы будете накручивать слушатели на кнопку и проводить  FragmentTransaction. Удачи.